# Mailpoet Sign up on Custom registration form won't work

Tags: plugins, api, newsletter

I've been trying to solve this myself for hours but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

I have a custom registration form on my website and I would like to add a checkbox for users to sign up for the newsletter.

I went through the [Mailpoet Docs](https://beta.docs.mailpoet.com/article/195-add-subscribers-through-your-own-form-or-plugin) and tried everything that they describe there but something is not working for me.

The user is being signed up successfully but never gets added to my mainling list. Here's my code

```
function newsletterSignUp(){
    $subscriber_data = array(
      'email' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']),
      'first_name' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['first_name']),
      'last_name' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['last_name'])
    );

    $list = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0][id];
    //Returns the ID of the list that I want to assign subscribers to 

    try {
      $subscriber = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->addSubscriber($subscriber_data, $list, $options);
    } catch(Exception $exception) {
      // return $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I am calling this function like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Some other code to sign up the user

   if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])){  //The name of my checkbox input
     newsletterSignUp();
   }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

On this line here:

```
$list = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0][id];
```

You're missing quotes around `id`, so `$list` isn't being set to the ID. You need to add quotes:

```
$list = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0]['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I’ve been dealing with the same general problem today and turned this up in the process of resolving my issue, I thought it would be worthwhile to make an observation that may help others to proceed.

Besides the omission of quotes noted by Jacob Peattie, I see a problem with the second (optional) parameter in `addSubscriber()`. That second parameter needs to be an array — see [Mailpoet’s documentation](https://github.com/mailpoet/mailpoet/blob/master/doc/api_methods/AddSubscriber.md#list_ids-optional) on this. Even if only adding the user to a single list, the parameter should be an array (a one-element array in this case).

So instead of

```
$list = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0]['id'];
```

and

```
$subscriber = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->addSubscriber($subscriber_data, $list, $options);
```

it should be something like

```
$list = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0]['id'];
$list_ids = array( $list );
```

with

```
$subscriber = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->addSubscriber($subscriber_data, $list_ids, $options);
```